# Calling module params from custom field type

Tags: module, custom-module, fields

I've created a module which has a number of settings, one of which uses a custom field type defined within my module. The custom field essentially generates a dropdown list which is populated with data.

To decide which data should be added, though, I need to access some other parameters in the settings file. I've tried using `$this->form->getValue(param)` where param is the name of the field I'm trying to access, but it returns nothing.

Couldn't find anything specific in the documentation for this.

Comment: I assume you putting the name of the param in quotes like so `->getValue('param')`

Comment: @Lodder I am. The actual call looks like `$this->form->getValue("fallBeginning")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot to specify `container` of the form fields. Your code should be something like

```
$this->form->getValue('fallBeginning', 'container')
```

if your field has actual html code like

```
<input type="text" name="container[fallBeginning]" value="x">
```

The `container` value depends on your xml definition, what is the name of `fields`. For example

```
<form>
    <fields name="container">
```